# Where should I look for the Necronomicon?

Tags: the-curious-expedition

In "The Curious Expedition", finding the Necronomicon on Normal or higher difficulty will unlock H.P. Lovecraft as a playable character. In one of my first games on Easy difficulty, I found it, but I can't remember what type of location it was at (tomb, shrine, cave, etc.)

Is there a specific type of location that I look for the Necronomicon in, or is there just a low-percentage chance to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is just a low chance of finding the [Necronomicon](http://curious-expedition.wikia.com/wiki/Necronomicon).

[This thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/358130/discussions/0/358416640393410289/) has players finding it in Shrines and Temples, and claiming that treasure maps can also be used to find the Necronomicon. I can also confirm from personal experience that it is a rare find. I've found it twice, both times in shrines.

So I think you'll just have to keep grinding and hope you find it, though I would make a point of exploring temples and shrines to maximize your chances of finding it and unlocking [H. P. Lovecraft](http://curious-expedition.wikia.com/wiki/H._P._Lovecraft).

Happy Expeditions!

Comment: I finally found it not too long ago in a Shrine. Thanks!

Comment: @Discord Glad I could help!